# Using COALESCE to handle NULL values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, null, coalesce

I have the following query

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
     pt.incentive_marketing, 
     pt.incentive_channel, 
     pt.incentive_advertising 
FROM test.pricing pt 
WHERE pt.contract_id = 90000 
group by 1,2,3 
order by pt.incentive_marketing;
```

The above query returns the o/p as shown in the attached image
[image]

**However I want to replace all null values by 0 using COALESCE**
Please let me know how this can be achieved in above SELECT query

Now I further modified the query using coalesce as below

```
SELECT  
     COALESCE( pt.incentive_marketing, '0' ), 
     COALESCE(pt.incentive_channel,'0'), 
     COALESCE( pt.incentive_advertising,'0') 
FROM test.pricing pt 
WHERE pt.contract_id = 90000 
group by 1,2,3
```

the result of which is as attached in image 2.

I still receive one row with blank values

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to replace null values with zeroes using `COALESCE`? What exactly went wrong?

Comment: no I havent tried , please show me using coalesce

Comment: Then please try the coalesce() function and report any problem you have with it. Read the manual if you are unsure about how to use it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL - "*No I haven't tried*" isn't the way SO works.

Comment: Additionally: using `distinct` **and** `group by` doesn't make sense. `group by 1,2,3` already makes all columns distinct. So does the `distinct` operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I have used the coalesce and eadited the question , please see

Comment: You may have empty strings in addition to null values there - these won't be altered by coalesce(), you need to use some "case" statement. Why your numbers are strings anyway?

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing NULL's? Or is it an empty string '' your seeing? Change pgAdmin-settings to show <NULL> where you have a NULL, instead of an empty field that could be NULL or ''.

Comment: HI I have used case statement and it worked

Comment: Why are you storing nulls as '', 0, and null?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` in conjunction with `NULLIF` for a short, efficient solution:

```
COALESCE( NULLIF(yourField,'') , '0' )
```

[The `NULLIF` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15302) will return null if `yourField` is equal to the second value (`''` in the example), making the `COALESCE` function fully working on all cases:

```
                 QUERY                     |                RESULT 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(null  ,''),'0')     |                 '0'
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(''    ,''),'0')     |                 '0'
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF('foo' ,''),'0')     |                 'foo'
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using `0` and an empty string `''` and `null` to designate undefined you've got a data problem. Just update the columns and fix your schema.

```
UPDATE pt.incentive_channel
SET   pt.incentive_marketing = NULL
WHERE pt.incentive_marketing = '';

UPDATE pt.incentive_channel
SET   pt.incentive_advertising = NULL
WHERE pt.incentive_marketing = '';

UPDATE pt.incentive_channel
SET   pt.incentive_channel = NULL
WHERE pt.incentive_marketing = '';
```

This will make joining and selecting substantially easier moving forward.