# Postgres placeholders for 0 data

Tags: postgresql

I have some Postgres data like this:

```
date       | count
2015-01-01 | 20
2015-01-02 | 15
2015-01-05 | 30
```

I want to run a query that pulls this data with 0s in place for the dates that are missing, like this:

```
date       | count
2015-01-01 | 20
2015-01-02 | 15
2015-01-03 |  0
2015-01-04 |  0
2015-01-05 | 30
```

This is for a very large range of dates, and I need it to fill in all the gaps.  How can I accomplish this with just SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a table `junk` of:

```
     d      | c  
------------+----
 2015-01-01 | 20
 2015-01-02 | 15
 2015-01-05 | 30
```

Running

```
select fake.d, coalesce(j.c, 0) as c
from (select min(d) + generate_series(0,7,1) as d from junk) fake
     left outer join junk j on fake.d=j.d;
```

gets us:

```
     d      |     c 
------------+----------
 2015-01-01 |       20
 2015-01-02 |       15
 2015-01-03 |        0
 2015-01-04 |        0
 2015-01-05 |       30
 2015-01-06 |        0
 2015-01-07 |        0
 2015-01-08 |        0
```

You could of course adjust the start date for the series, length it runs for, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this data going? To an outside source or another table or view?

There's probably a better solution but you could create a new table(or in excel wherever the data is going) that has the entire date-range you want with another integer column of null values. Then update that table with your current dataset then replace all nulls with zero.

It's a really roundabout way to do things but it'll work.

I don't have enough rep to comment :(

This is also a good reference
[Using COALESCE to handle NULL values in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479180/using-coalesce-to-handle-null-values-in-postgresql)

Comment: I don't see why it makes a difference.  It's going to plug into a report framework that requires pure SQL, so I can't manipulate it with code at all.  Note that questions should be entered as comments to my post, not as answers.