# How to join 2 tables to get more data of left table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, database-design

I am using Postgresql to query data.

What I have done as below:

Table1:

```
#id #zone_id    #name   #timestamp_create
1   1           Alex    2016-08-10 11:00:11.07+00
2   1           James   2016-08-10 11:30:11.07+00
3   1           Mary    2016-08-10 11:45:11.07+00
4   1           Ken     2016-08-10 12:15:11.07+00
5   1           Aston   2016-08-10 12:45:11.07+00
6   2           Tom     2016-08-11 11:28:11.07+00
7   2           Edward  2016-08-11 11:30:11.07+00
```

Table2:

```
#id #zone_id    #code   #timestamp_start            #timestamp_end
1   1           A       2016-08-10 10:50:11.07+00   2016-08-10 11:15:11.07+00
2   1           B       2016-08-10 11:16:11.07+00   2016-08-10 11:50:11.07+00
3   2           E       2016-08-11 10:30:11.07+00   2016-08-11 10:30:11.07+00
```

My Query:

```
SELECT t1.zone_id, t1.name, t2.code, t1.timestamp_create
FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.zone_id = t2.zone_id
WHERE t1.timestamp_create BETWEEN t2.timestamp_start AND t2.timestamp_end
```

Result:

```
#zone_id    #name   #code   #timestamp_create
1           Alex    A       2016-08-10 11:00:11.07+00
1           James   B       2016-08-10 11:30:11.07+00
1           Mary    B       2016-08-10 11:45:11.07+00
```

How can I achieve the result below:

```
 #zone_id   #name   #code   #timestamp_create
 1          Alex    A       2016-08-10 11:00:11.07+00
 1          James   B       2016-08-10 11:30:11.07+00
 1          Mary    B       2016-08-10 11:45:11.07+00
 1          Ken             2016-08-10 12:15:11.07+00
 1          Aston           2016-08-10 12:45:11.07+00
```

I also tried to use LEFT OUTER JOIN, but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply switching to `left join` won't work because you have a condition in your `where` that involves the columns of the right table. For the rows that don't match, those columns will contain `null`, so they won't satisfy the condition.

To achieve what you want you have switch to `left join` and move that condition to the `on` clause

```
SELECT  t1.zone_id,
        t1.name,
        t2.code,
        t1.timestamp_create
FROM    table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN
        table2 as t2 
ON      t1.zone_id = t2.zone_id AND
        t1.timestamp_create BETWEEN t2.timestamp_start AND t2.timestamp_end
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, in case I wanna avoid of null value, how can I replace null with a text, supposed "n/a" or "undefined"

Comment: Ok, I found solution for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479180/using-coalesce-to-handle-null-values-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join`, but you have to move conditions to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT t1.zone_id, t1.name, t2.code, t1.timestamp_create
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.zone_id = t2.zone_id AND
        t1.timestamp_create BETWEEN t2.timestamp_start AND t2.timestamp_end
```

Comment: You missed the `LEFT` in your query